# Possible overtakes a chess piece can make as a List? One liner java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Given a 2D array of a `Piece`. Has location etc.

```
Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];
```

Given a pair-value `Location` object (row, col).

Given a validator that validates moves (standard chess):

```
public boolean isValidMove(Piece piece, Location toLocation) { ... }
```

I wrote this:

```
/**
 * Generates a List of possible overtakes for a Piece.
 * 
 * @param piece
 *            Piece that will be overtaking another.
 * @return A List of possible overtakes the piece can make.
 */
public List<Piece> possibleMoves(Piece piece) {

    return Stream.of(board.getBoard()).flatMap(Stream::of).filter(
        p -> p != null && isValidMove(piece, p.getLocation())).collect(
            Collectors.toList());

}
```

But this will only return the `Piece` that it can overtake. How can I get only the `Location`?

Also another question, this looks fancy and all but performance-wise. Is it better or worse than a double for loop in anyway?

Comment: Once you have your list of pieces, can yo just call `getLocation()` on each?

Comment: Stream.of(board.getBoard()).flatMap(Stream::of).filter(
            p -> p != null && isValidMove(piece, p.getLocation())).map(p -> p.getLocation()).collect(
                Collectors.toList()); ?? @Jeremy

Comment: Also another question, this looks fancy and all but performance-wise. Is it better or worse than a double for loop in anyway?

Comment: No difference in practice.